# Keeping instances of a recurring event synchronized

Tags: google-calendar-api

I've been trying all day to figure out how to "rehydrate" instances of a recurring event from my app.

Let me explain the flow real quick:

1. User grants access to my app to edit their calendar
2. The app sets up a recurring event
3. The app subscribes to the `/watch` endpoint for that calendar

So far so good, now when the creator moves that event to another time, I get a notification on the webhook url, which is fine (well, sorta), it looks like this:

```
  'x-goog-channel-id': 'my_specified_channel_id',
  'x-goog-channel-expiration': 'Thu, 29 Sep 2016 12:58:10 GMT',
  'x-goog-resource-state': 'exists',
  'x-goog-message-number': '333384',
  'x-goog-resource-id': 'some-resource-id',  // This id apparently has nothing to do with any resources I know of
  'x-goog-resource-uri': 'https://www.googleapis.com/.../resource-uri'
```

So I would figure that I could call `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/some-resource-id` and get the updated resource, but the `resource-id` doesn't seem to have anything to do with any events in the calendar, nor is it the id of the calendar itself (I use the `'primary'` keyword)

So I thought, I could as a work-around get all the instances of the recurring event using the `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/recurring-event-id/instances` endpoint, but now the event that was moved is no longer part of that payload anymore. I'm guessing google removes the event from the parent event because it doesn't happen at the same time of day anymore (I haven't been able to confirm this anywhere)?

So what I'm asking is:

1. Am I interpreting `x-goog-resource-id` wrong?
2. Can someone confirm that once an event is edited from the google calendar app it looses its relation to the recurring parent event?

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#understanding-the-notification-message-format), the X-Goog-Resource-ID is an opaque value that identifies the watched resource. This ID is stable across API versions.

Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents) to know more about Reccuring Events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

1. `x-goog-resource-id` is the identifier of the calendar, as that is the entity you're putting the watcher on
2. Once an event that is part of a recurring set is edited, it is no longer part of that set